# How to manipulate dynamically created comboboxes in VBA?

Tags: vba, userform

I am dynamically creating comboboxes on a userform in sets of 3: a category, a subcategory, and an item/unit.
My goal is to adjust the list of the comboboxes based on selection. For example if a certain category is selected, the linked subcategory and item combobox lists are limited to the entries of that specific category. Same for the subcategory -> item.
I have an array with all items' name, category and subcategory, which I use to fill up the comboboxes.

My problem is trying to code the class module and event, as I am not yet familiar in how those work in enough detail. For a simplified test I am trying to make it work with just the category + subcategory options.
I use the following code to add + fill these within the userform's code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim cbNew As clsComboBox
Dim AddedComboboxes As Collection
Public WithEvents ActiveComboBox As clsComboBox

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim arrCat() As Variant, arrSubCat() As Variant

Set AddedComboboxes = New Collection   

'code here to fill comboboxes

Set cbNew = New clsComboBox
With cbNew
    Set .ComboBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Combobox.1", "cbCat1")
    .ComboBox.Height = 18
    .ComboBox.Left = 18
    .ComboBox.Top = 12
    .ComboBox.Width = 186
End With
AddedComboboxes.Add Item:=cbNew

cbNew.ComboBox.List = arrCat

Set cbNew = New clsComboBox
With cbNew
    Set .ComboBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Combobox.1", "cbSubCat1")
    .ComboBox.Height = 18
    .ComboBox.Left = 18
    .ComboBox.Top = 42
    .ComboBox.Width = 186
End With
AddedComboboxes.Add Item:=cbNew

cbNew.ComboBox.List = arrSubCat

End Sub

Private Sub ActiveComboBox_Change()
Dim k As Integer, i As Integer
Dim arrTempSubCat() As Variant

If ActiveComboBox.ComboBox.Name = "cbCat1" Then
    
    'counter for first item
    k = 0
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrUnit, 2)
        If arrUnit(i, 2) = ActiveComboBox.ComboBox.Value Then
            If k > 0 Then
                For j = 1 To UBound(arrTempSubCat)
                    If arrUnit(i, 3) = arrTempSubCat(j) Then
                        GoTo skip
                    End If
                Next j
                
                ReDim Preserve arrTempSubCat(1 To UBound(arrTempSubCat) + 1)
                arrTempSubCat(UBound(arrTempSubCat)) = arrUnit(i, 3)
            Else
                ReDim Preserve arrTempSubCat(1 To 1)
                arrTempSubCat(1) = arrUnit(i, 3)
                k = 1
            End If
        End If
skip:
    Next i
    
    Me.cbSubCat.List = arrTempSubCat
    
End If

End Sub
```

and I made the following class module, but I am obviously lost on how to proceed as the change event does not seem to trigger when I make selections in the combobox.

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents ComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox

Event Change()

Private Sub ComboBox_Change()
    RaiseEvent Change
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to `Set ActiveComboBox =` at some point.  Are you doing this?

Comment: I do not, only the `Set cbNew = New clsComboBox` lines I included. The only parts of code I omitted are just array definitions. I believe I understand the problem to be that the comboboxes are not linked to the change event through the class module. If this is the case, how can this be fixed?

Comment: Since you have code to respond to the Change event on the ActiveComboBox, you need to manage this object by `Set ActiveComboBox =` as needed.

Comment: Strange, the previous code I recycled was based on https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/dynamic-checkbox-control-in-a-vba-userform.1136840/post-5502569 where there is no set command for the active item object. Could you specify how I would need to set it to the currently active combobox, or what am I missing in the solution?

Comment: In looking at the sample code you referenced, the author is setting the ActiveComboBox in the Click event inside the class.

Comment: In the end I managed to make it work by adjusting the referenced code again, however it still remains a black box for me with the UFParent property loop. Unfortunately when I try to step through the procedure to see what the variables do the program keeps freezing all the time.